# Unable to set the value of a input text dynamically

Tags: jquery

When clciked on a plus or minus icon , i am trying to set the value of a input text of the below element

```
<input type="text" class="QtyInput" value="0">
```

Even though i increased the quantity and when i inspected the element it is still

shown with the value as zero

please see the screen shot below

http://jsfiddle.net/673h38g9/21/

[image]

Comment: why are you inspecting the element to see its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are checking is the value of the attribute, the actual value of the element is a property which is updated when you use `.val()`. The `value` attribute is used to set the initial value of the element.

```
$(document).on('click', '.icon-minus', function (e) {
    var value = parseInt($(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').val());
    if(value>=1)
    {
        var value = parseInt($(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').val());
        var $input = $(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput');
        $input.val(value-1);
        console.log('value-', $input.val(), $input.attr('value'), $input.prop('value'))

    }

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/673h38g9/23/)

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the attribute of element, .val() is property of input element here. to set the value attribute you should use:

```
 $(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').attr('value',currentquantity);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

just an example

```
$(this).attr('value', value);

$(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').attr('value', currentquantity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes inspect element will show the initial value only. But when you post the form it will take the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').attr("value",your value);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/673h38g9/24/)**